# Apollo Client Relay Style Pagination - Paginated Reads

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

In the docs for https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/cursor-based/

It states that

> Note that the relayStylePagination function generates a field policy with a read function that simply returns all available data, ignoring args, which makes relayStylePagination easier to use with fetchMore. This is a non-paginated read function. There's nothing stopping you from adapting this read function to use args to return individual pages, as long as you remember to update the variables of your original query after calling fetchMore.

I have been unable to find an example of what a paginated read function would look like.  Does anyone know of an example or can someone point me in the right direction?  The non-paginated read function works as expected.